# How do I detect collisions in a 2D project in Unity (without using a RigidBody2D)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying my hands on Unity for the first time and, as a "hello-world" kind of project I'm aiming for a 2D "Asteroids" game.

I'm advancing well, but the collisions are causing me headaches. They don't register. I've tries with and without a RigidBody. But The RB forced me to set it to Kinematic as it would otherwise fall down due to gravity, which is not what I want in a top-down shooter.

I tried setting "Full Kinematic Contacts" without any luck.

There are many different possible combinations and I can't find the right one. Rigid Body or not? Collider or not? Maybe both?

Here's a little demo project that reproduces the issue. I would *expect* it to show a log-line in the console when the circle touches the square. But it does not. How do I get that done?

https://github.com/exhuma/unity-collision-test

Comment: just remove gravity from the rigidbody environment. I remember it was on a system wide option set somewhere but I've not been on Unity for years. Rigidbody is the way to go for collision detection I think. See here : https://answers.unity.com/questions/1208841/how-to-disable-gravity-on-collision-of-rigidbody2d.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The RB forced me to set it to Kinematic as it would otherwise fall
> down due to gravity

You may uncheck the gravity in Rigidbody component. (Gravity Scale on Rigidbody2D)
Rigidbody is a way to contact with physics.

> Rigid Body or not? Collider or not? Maybe both?

Add both.

I had viewed you code on github and I would like to suggest

Use Velocity

```
rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(300 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

instead of

```
transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * 3);
```

and also add

```
public Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
void Start()
{
     rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

The script attached gameobject must have Rigidbody2D
[image]
Here is the doc link:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. That helped. And yes. With a rigid-body I can now use a bit more of the interesting physics simulations like using velocity and impulse.